# geom_bar ggplot2 plotting category but assigning colour scales based on an additional factor

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, geom-bar, stacked-chart

I am wondering if there is anyway to adjust how to colour the geom_bar stack graphs by a different component than the plotted one?

To clarify say I have a data frame with four components: species, count, date and type.

```
   species count       date type
1        a    20 2016-05-22  Phy
2        b    34 2016-05-22  Phy
3        c    45 2016-05-22  Phy
4        d     4 2016-05-22  Zoo
5        e    43 2016-05-22  Zoo
6        f     9 2016-05-22 Bact
7        g    19 2016-05-22 Bact
8        h    32 2016-05-22 Bact
9        a    16 2016-05-23  Phy
10       b     0 2016-05-23  Phy
11       c     0 2016-05-23  Phy
12       d     2 2016-05-23  Zoo
13       e    42 2016-05-23  Zoo
14       f    23 2016-05-23 Bact
15       g    22 2016-05-23 Bact
16       h    21 2016-05-23 Bact
```

So my problem is I would like to plot a stacked bar  in ggplot:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = date, y=count, group = species, fill = Species)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity")
```

However, I would like the colour of the bars to be determined by the "type", with each category in type having its own colour scale. Such that if species a-c are all in "Phy" category the species a, b and c would be, for example, different shades of blue.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you!
L

Comment: As a start, if you load `library(scales)` you can start generating different shades of particular colours like: `c(brewer_pal(palette = "Blues")(5), brewer_pal(palette = "Greens")(3))`.

Comment: Colouring by more than one factor rarely results in an effective visualisation. I would fill by species and use facets for type. Can post an answer using that approach if you like.

Comment: @neilfws that would be great actually to see an example like that too please! - Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution as per the comment thread, using facets for type and colours for species. It may be less effective than this example in practice, depending on how many dates, types and species there are in the data.

```
ggplot(df, aes(date, count)) + 
  geom_col(aes(fill = species)) + 
  facet_grid(. ~ type) + 
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Spectral") +
  theme_light()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the example - I think with my actual data i might, like you mention, have too many dates/species. I will give it a try non-the-less. Thank you for the code it is definitely good to consider different ways of presenting the data!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that reorders the species factor by type and then stitches together different colour palettes. Pick different palettes if you don't like the specific colours generated.

```
library(forcats)
library(tidyverse)
library(scales)

# Reorder the levels of the species factor by type
df = df %>%
    mutate(species = fct_reorder(species, as.numeric(type)))
unique_df = df %>% distinct(type, species)
type_counts = table(unique_df$type)

colours = character(0)
# Need to manually fill this at least up to the number of types
palettes = c("Blues", "Greens", "Reds")

for (i in 1:length(type_counts)) {
    colours = c(colours, brewer_pal(palette = palettes[i])(type_counts[i]))
}

ggplot(df, aes(x = date, y=count, group = species, fill = species)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", colour = "black") +
    scale_fill_manual(values = colours) +
    theme_bw()
```

[image: Plot]

Comment: Thank you @Marius - I will give this a try!

Comment: @Lmm: you can always add `facet_wrap(~ type)` to my plotting code and get the benefits of both solutions.

Comment: Which package is the brewer_pal function from? Thank you for the feedback!

Comment: `scales`, I did load it in my example code. `scales` contains a lot of the functions `ggplot` uses to generate colours.

Answer (score 0):

This type of data is much better suited to a [slopegraph](http://charliepark.org/slopegraphs/). This shows you clear patterns that are not visible with your stacked barchart.

For example, it's now obvious that although the bacterial species were of heterogeneous abundance on day 1, the treatment caused them to converge to a single abundance on day 2. The plants were all deleteriously affected by the treatment, some sharply but "a" only slightly. The animals were barely affected at all, keeping their previous community structure.

```
require(dplyr)

ggplot(df, aes(date, count, group = species)) +
  facet_grid(type ~ .) +
  geom_line(aes(colour = type), size = 3, show.legend = F) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_text(data = function(x) {x %>% filter(date == min(date))},
            aes(label = species), nudge_x = -.025) + 
  theme_bw()
```

[image]